# Why Do Open Bounties Prevent Close Votes?

Tags: discussion

See this question:
[Recommend an open source, template driven website builder UI that produces a working WordPress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/recommend-an-open-source-template-driven-website-builder-ui-that-produces-a-wor)

I attempted to close-vote this question as **too localized**, based on the OP's comments to the posted answers, indicating that each one fails to meet his unique requirements. To me, those responses indicate that the question is too narrowly scoped. But, when I attempted to close-vote, the system indicated that the question could not be closed, due to the open bounty.

Why?

This seems like a potential flaw in the system. Someone can ask any question they want - on topic or off, constructive or not, too localized or not, duplicate or not - and the community will be unable to close the question. Essentially, someone can "buy" the right to ask any question whatsoever, merely by sacrificing a few Rep points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only set bounties after two days, so the situation that a question with a bounty needs to be closed occurs only rarely. Most bad questions should be caught before someone can set a bounty on them.

Moderators can refund bounties, which allows them to then close the question like usual. If you think a question with a bounty should be closed, you should flag for a moderator as you cannot act yourself in this special case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, with the volume of low-quality questions we get at WPSE, it is not uncommon for a low-quality question simply to remain unnoticed/ignored for those two days. Thus, a question remaining open for two days is in no way indicative of the community's overall assessment of the quality of the question. In any case, I've done as you suggested, and flagged the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question for which a bounty has been placed, but which should instead be closed:
[Strip Twitter Username from Profile Field with URL and Save to New Profile Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/strip-twitter-username-from-profile-field-with-url-and-save-to-new-profile-field)

The question, as stated, is answered fully by the posted answer. Instead of accepting the answer, the OP kept expanding the scope of the question (in the comments), to the point where the question now becomes **not a real question** any longer, as it is now a *do my coding work for me* question.

@TomJNowell has done yeoman's work in his answer and comments, trying to explain site mechanics to the OP, to no avail. At the very least, Tom will get the bounty Rep for all of his mostly-fruitless hard work.