# Why my flag for moderator attention for a post was declined?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging, off-topic, bounty

I flagged [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255142/allow-logged-in-users-who-doesnt-belong-to-whitelisted-ips) for moderator attention as I thought it to be off topic based on [this Help Center article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

More specifically, the following point:

> generic server configuration and administration.

Also, since the question has an open bounty, I couldn't flag to close it directly. Then I searched in meta and found [this answer](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1028/110572). It suggests:

> If you think a question with a bounty should be closed, you should flag for a moderator as you cannot act yourself in this special case.

Which is what I did, but then I received the following for the flag:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

I'm just trying to understand, nothing more. Where am I wrong in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at this and was on the fence whether it should be moved or not. Ultimately, I left it be as it had to do with the WordPress user login. While at a glance it does look like generic HTAccess configuration, after reading the question it is specifically aimed at HTAcess for WordPress accounts + whitelisted IPs.

I don't think you're necessarily wrong in this case but because it does blur the lines, it was left open.

Comment: Interesting point. I see your reasoning. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Fayaz also when a Q is off-topic for you, is better to use your vote to close it instead of to ask moderator to act. SE should be as much as community-moderated as possible. I try to never use mod power to close a question, unless it is spam or something like that.

Comment: @gmazzap actually I tried to do that (please read my question), but the system rejected that action, since the Q had an open bounty.

Comment: @Fayaz typed too fast, sorry. The issue is I would never use mod power to close a bounty Q, unless clearly spam or offensive or something like that. I guess downvote is what I would do if I would feel  a bounty Q is off topic.

Comment: @gmazzap that's the thing - my intention is not to close, rather to transfer it to the right site, so that it gets proper answer. Ultimately that's the purpose of all these community work, right? Anyways, I get your point. Thanks for the comment.